# How do i change an image in tkinter using a def statement

Tags: python, tkinter

I seem to have a problem with the following code

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.geometry("1000x1000")

window.title(" Team Insanity login")

photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="content-large-white.gif")

def login():

    user = entuser.get()

    password = entpassword.get()

    if (user == "X-box") and (password == "d0ct0r"):
       photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Trmn8atrmn8ter.gif")
       lblname.configure(text = "Welcome X-box!")

    elif (user == "Chloe") and (password == "l3ad3r"):
       photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="chloecat194.gif")
       lblname.configure(text = "Welcome Chloe!")

    lblpicture.configure(image=photo)

lblpicture = tkinter.Label(window, image=photo)

lblname = tkinter.Label(text="Please log in")

entuser = tkinter.Entry(window)

entpassword = tkinter.Entry(window)

btnlogin = tkinter.Button(text="Login", command=login)

lblname.pack()

lblpicture.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

entuser.pack()

entpassword.pack()

btnlogin.pack()



window.mainloop
```

You see, when attempting to run, it works fine. The login works as well, as it changes lblname's text. However, it does not seem to remember the changed picture, as it returns to a grey the same size as the picture requested.

it is also of note that, during debugging, i found that if a incorrectly spelled .update command made the picture stay up, but when corrected, made it flash the picture before reverting.

I'm not sure if it matters, but here are the pictures I am using

Trmn8atrmn8ter.gif = convert of http://chloecat194.deviantart.com/art/X-box-432590753?q=gallery%3AChloecat194%2F34413920&qo=16

Chloecat194.gif = convert of http://chloecat194.deviantart.com/art/Chloecat194-432590268?q=gallery%3AChloecat194%2F34413920&qo=18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `login`, `photo` is a local variable. When the `login` function ends, the *local* variable `photo` may be garbage collected. [Fredrik Lundh explains](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm) the problem this way:

> When Python’s garbage collector discards the Tkinter object, Tkinter
>   tells Tk to release the image. But since the image is in use by a
>   widget, Tk doesn’t destroy it. Not completely. It just blanks the
>   image, making it completely transparent…

The solution is to keep a reference to the PhotoImage. Since you aren't using classes, the easiest way to keep a reference is to make `photo` a global variable:

```
def login():
    global photo
    ...
    lblpicture.configure(image=photo)
```

This will also allow the `content-large-white.gif` to be the default image if neither the `if-condition` or the `elif-condition` is True; as it stands, Python raises a `UnboundLocalError` if it reaches that case.